# Test file update in cakephp 4 with phpunit

Tags: testing, cakephp, file-upload, phpunit, laminas

I'm doing the test for the files I upload but in the test the file is treated as a string and I need a Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile. How can I mock this for the test?

I have this is my controller:

```
        $animal = $this->Animal->patchEntity($animal, $this->request->getData());
         if(!$animal->getErrors){
            $image = $this->request->getData('image_file');
            if($image && ($image->getClientMediaType()!='image/png' && $image->getClientMediaType()!='image/jpg'&& $image->getClientMediaType()!='image/jpeg' && $image->getClientFilename()!="")){
```

And this in my test:

```
        $_FILES = [
        'image_file' => [
            'name'     => 'student-import-test-1.csv',
            'type'     => 'text/csv',
            'tmp_name' => 'tests/Fixture/csv/',
            'error'    => 0,
            'size'     => 258
        ]
    ];

    $data=[
        'name' => 'AñadirAnimal',
        'image_file'     => 'student-import-test-1.csv',
        'image_file.type'     => 'text/csv',
        'image_file.tmp_name' => 'tests/Fixture/csv/',
        'image_file.error'    => 0,
        'image_file.size'     => 258,
        'specie' => 'dog',
        'chip' => 'no',
        'sex' => 'intact_male',
        'race' => 'cat',
        'age' => 1,
        'information' => 'Es un animal.',
        'state' => 'sick',
        'animal_shelter' => [
            'start_date' => '2022-11-03 10:47:38',
            'end_date' => '2023-05-03 10:47:38',
            'user_id' => 1,
            'animal_id' => 1
        ]
    ];
```

My question is how can I create the Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile on the $data in the test.

Answer (score 0):

To create a \Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile;

```
$data=[
        
        'name' => 'AñadirAnimal',
        'specie' => 'dog',
        'chip' => 'no',
        'sex' => 'intact_male',
        'race' => 'cat',
        'age' => 1,
        'information' => 'Es un animal.',
        'image_file' => new \Laminas\Diactoros\UploadedFile(
            '/tmp/hfz6dbn.tmp',
            123,
            \UPLOAD_ERR_OK,
            'attachment.txt',
            'text/plain'
            ),
        'state' => 'sick',
        'animal_shelter' => [
            'start_date' => '2022-11-03 10:47:38',
            'end_date' => '2023-05-03 10:47:38',
            'user_id' => 1,
            'animal_id' => 1
        ]
    ];
```